# xcode apple mach-o linker (id) error c++

Tags: c++, xcode8

Hi I've encounter "apple mach-o linker (id) error" while programming with Xcode 8 in c++. I've tried all procedures to solve it but no one works. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZu5e.png)

It seems in a first view that I've a problem when I call a method of another file, even though I've set the path of all "#include"

Comment: Did you also set up the linker correctly? My guess is you didn't. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Actually no. How can I make it?